# Uniform continuity preserves uniqueness of convergent sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-continuity, epsilon-delta

> If $f: (a, b) \to \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous, $\{x_n\}$ and $\{x'_n\}$ are sequences in $(a, b)$ with $x_n \to b$, $x'_n \to b$, $f(x_n) \to y$, and $f(x'_n) \to \overline{y}$, prove $y = y'$.

So by the definition of convergent sequence, we know that for all $\delta > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $d(x_n, b) < \delta$ for all $n > N$, and similarly a $N'$ with $x'_n$, so we can just take the max of $N$ and $N'$.

I'm not sure how to use uniform continuity here. We can't say that if $n > N$, then $d(x_n, b) < \delta \implies d(f(x_n), f(b)) < \epsilon$ by uniform confinuity since $b$ is not in the domain of the function, so $f(b)$ doesn't make sense.

What is the correct approach I should take? Is there a way to use Cauchy sequences here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Define a sequence by $(\tilde{x}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} := (x_1,x_1',x_2,x_2',\ldots)$.

- Show that $(f(\tilde{x}_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence; hence, convergent.
- Choosing suitable subsequences, deduce that the limit equals $y$ and $y'$; hence, $y=y'$.

Comment: So we don't need uniform continuity here? I don't think we need it to show $(f(\tilde{x}_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy since $d(x_n, b) < \delta \not\implies d(f(x_n), f(b)) < \epsilon$ since $b \not\in (a, b)$ so $f(b)$ doesn't make sense, and the same with $d(x'_n, b)$

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs Actually, we *do* need the uniform continuity in order to prove that $(f(\tilde{x}_n))_n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: I tried by first using the definition of convergent sequence, since $x_n \to b$ we have for all $\delta > 0$ that $d(x_n, b) < \delta$ for all $n > N$, but when I try to use uniform convergence, I get $d(x_n, b) < \delta \implies d(f(x_n), f(b)) < \epsilon$ which is not possible since $b$ is not in the domain and so $f(b)$ is not in the image

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs Since $x_n \to b$ and $x_n' \to b$, it follows that $\tilde{x}_n \to b$. In particular, for any $\delta>0$ there exists $N$ such that $|\tilde{x}_n-\tilde{x}_m| \leq \delta$ for all $n,m \geq N$. Now use that $f$  is uniformly continuous, to conclude that for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find $N$ such that $|f(\tilde{x}_n)-f(\tilde{x}_m)| \leq \epsilon$ for all $n,m \geq N$.